# Example of limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, epsilon-delta

I'm self-studying from the book [Understanding Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387950605) by Stephen Abbott, and I don't understand example 4.2.2 on page 105.

The aim of the example is to show that:
$$
\lim_{x \to 2} g(x) = 4
$$ 
where $g(x) = x^2$.

The author starts by writing:
$$
|g(x) - 4| = |x^2 - 4 | = |x+2||x-2|
$$
which I understand. But then the following paragraph makes no sense to me:

> We can make $|x-2|$ as small as we like, but we need an upper bound on $|x+2|$ in order to know how small to choose $\delta$. The presence of the variable $x$ causes some initial confusion, but keep in mind that we are discussing the limit as $x$ approaches $2$. If we  agree that our $\delta$-neighborhood around $c = 2$ must have radius no bigger than $\delta = 1$, then we get the upper bound $|x + 2| \leq |3 + 2| = 5$ for all $x \in V_\delta(c)$.

By saying we are only considering the $\delta$-neighborhood around $c=2$ with a radius smaller than or equal to $1$, I would think we get:
$$
V_\delta (c) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid |x-2| < 1 \} = (1,3)
$$
so I don't understand where "$|x + 2| \leq |3 + 2| = 5$ for all $x \in V_\delta(c)$" comes from? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If $\lvert x-2\rvert < 1$, that is, $1 < x < 3$, then $3 < x+2 < 5$, hence $\lvert x+2\rvert \leqslant 5$.

Comment: The first inequality is $1\lt x\lt 3$. @DanielFischer

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) here instead:
$$
|x + 2| = |(x - 2) + (4)| \leq |x - 2| + |4| < 1 + |4| = 5
$$

Comment: This really clarifies it and is very clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if $x \in V_{\delta}(c)$, we have $|x-2| < 1$. Since $||x|-|2|| \leq |x-2|$ we deduce: $|x|-2 \leq ||x|-|2|| \leq |x-2| < 1$. Then $|x| < 1+2=3$.

Now : $$|x+2| \leq |x| + |2| < 3+2=5$$

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted Adriano's answer because it cleaner, but this is still very useful. +1